# ExtJS Theming Multiple CSS Files

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sass, compass-sass, sencha-cmd

In earlier versions of ExtJS, `compass compile` would compile each sass file placed in the `resources/sass` into a separate CSS file.  For example:

app.scss ---> app.css

login.scss ---> login.css

I'm wondering if I can accomplish something similar using the new theme structure in ExtJS 4 (specifically 4.2.1), and have it nicely integrated with the entire build process covered by Sencha Cmd (running `sencha app build`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sencha Cmd build process will automatically compile any SASS files in the app's build directory. In the standard build process, Sencha Cmd generates SASS files for the theme automatically and places them in the build folder, but you can use the Ant integration of Sencha Cmd to copy your own SASS files as well.

Suppose you have a bunch of SASS stylesheets stored in a `sass/stylesheets` directory that you want to compile:

```
Project
 -> app
 -> build
     -> production
     -> testing
 -> resources
 -> sass
     -> etc
     -> example
     -> src
     -> var
     -> stylesheets
 -> build.xml
```

All you need to do is add the following target to your `build.xml` file, which will copy any `.scss` files in that folder to your build directory prior to the SASS compilation:

```
<target name="-before-sass">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${app.dir}/sass/stylesheets">
            <include name="*.scss"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Then, after running `sencha app build`, you should see a copy of your SASS files in `build/production` and the compiled CSS under `build/production/resources`.

Comment: Dark magic, Ext.js official documentation (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/theming) says that placing of *.scss files to /sacc/src folder is enough to include tehm into result CSS.

Answer (score 0):

if you have generated your application using [sencha-cmd](/questions/tagged/sencha-cmd), you'll see the following directories:

```
MyProject
--> app
--> build
--> ext
--> overrides
--> packages
--> resources
--> saas
    - etc
    - example
    - src
    - var
```

you can place you `css` styles to the **src** directory. remember that the path and filename should match the path as your view.

example: if you have a `LoginView.js` under your `app/view/`, you should add its css styles on `LogonView.scss` under `sass/src/view/`.

Comment: That will include my styles in the same stylesheet as the rest of the application.  I want to be able to define two separate stylesheets.